# Define event horizon using only the notions of events and causality

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, causality

Does this work?
Consider a set $B$ of events which satisfies 
If $x$ belongs to $B$ and $x$ causes $y$ then $y$ belongs to $B$. The event horizon of $B$ is the set of events that are not in $B$ but can be arbitrarily well approximated by points of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

For an observer defined by a timelike curve $\gamma$, the horizon of this observer is :

\begin{equation}
\text{Hor}(\gamma) = \partial \left( \bigcup_{p \in \gamma} I^-(p) \right)
\end{equation}

It's the boundary of all the points that are or will be in the past of that observer, so that he could not possibly observe any point beyond that set.

Comment: does the notion of event horizon require an observer?

Comment: In general, yes. The more common notion involves classes of observers, such as for black holes in asymptotically flat spacetimes, in which case it is the set of observers ending at null infinity.